# How to save QR code response into Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, qr-code

I am building an App that has movie list in a table view and once I press a button I can add a QR code data to Core Data and show it on the table view as well.
So far I have managed to get the QR code string to my label.
But now I want to save the response into Core Data.
how do I do that?
Thanks

```
    import UIKit
    import AVFoundation

    class CameraViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var messageView: UIView!
        @IBOutlet weak var messageLbl: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var topBar: UIView!

        var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
        var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
        var qrCodeFrameView: UIView?

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()


            let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

            do {
                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice) as AVCaptureDeviceInput
                captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
                captureSession?.addInput(input)
            } catch  {
                print(error)
                return
            }


            let captureMetaDataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
            captureSession?.addOutput(captureMetaDataOutput)
            captureMetaDataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            captureMetaDataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]
            videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
            videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
            videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
            view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)


            captureSession?.startRunning()
            view.bringSubview(toFront: messageLbl)
            view.bringSubview(toFront: topBar)
            view.bringSubview(toFront: messageView)


            qrCodeFrameView = UIView()

            if let newFrame = qrCodeFrameView {
                newFrame.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
                newFrame.layer.borderWidth = 2
                view.addSubview(newFrame)
                view.bringSubview(toFront: newFrame)
            }

        }

        func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

            if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects.count == 0 {
                qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRect.zero
                messageLbl.text = "No QR code is detected"
                return
            }

            let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

            if metadataObj.type == AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode {
                let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObj)
                qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject!.bounds

                if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
                    messageLbl.text = metadataObj.stringValue

                }
            }
        }

        @IBAction func goToList(_ sender: Any) {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

**MovieListTableView**
        import UIKit

```
class MovieListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var movieTableView: UITableView!



    var movie:[Movie] = [Movie]()
    var currentMovies:[Movie] = [Movie]()
    var counter = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        movie = Helpers.downloadJson()
        self.movieTableView.reloadData()
        sort()

    }

    func sort() {
        movie.sort(by: { $0.releaseYear < $1.releaseYear })
        movieTableView.reloadData()

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return movie.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MovieCell") as! MovieCell

        cell.createCell(movie: movie[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedMovie = movie[indexPath.row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToDetail", sender: selectedMovie)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let nextVC = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
        nextVC.movie = sender as! Movie
    }

    @IBAction func addTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let nextView = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "goToCamera") as! CameraViewController
        self.present(nextView, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you looked at any Core Data tutorials or examples?

Comment: I did and I still need help

Comment: Then you should show the code where you are attempting to save the data to Core Data. The fact that the string comes from a QR code is irrelevant

Comment: In this line of code:                                                                                      
         if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
                    messageLbl.text = metadataObj.stringValue
                }                                                                                                            I want to change this to somthing that saves to core data